# Sharp edges issue in image warping using BitMapMesh

Tags: android, image, distortion

I'm implementing image warping when a user drags on the screen using `drawBitmapMesh`. This is the code from android apidemos after making some changes.

```
private static final int WIDTH = 20;
private static final int HEIGHT = 20;
private static final int COUNT = (WIDTH + 1) * (HEIGHT + 1);
private static float[] mVerts = new float[COUNT*2];
private float[] mOrig = new float[COUNT*2];
private static Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
private static Matrix mInverse = new Matrix();
private static float[] dst; //Global

    //This is where I construct my mesh
    float w = mBitmap.getWidth();
    float h = mBitmap.getHeight();
    int index = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y <= HEIGHT; y++) {
        float fy = h * y / HEIGHT;
        for (int x = 0; x <= WIDTH; x++) {
            float fx = w * x / WIDTH;
            setXY(mVerts, index, fx, fy);
            setXY(mOrig, index, fx, fy);
            index += 1;

            dst = mVerts;//Assign dst here just once
            vertsCopy = mVerts.clone();
        }
    }
    mMatrix.setTranslate(10, 10);
    mMatrix.invert(mInverse);

private static void setXY(float[] array, int index, float x, float y) {
    array[index * 2 + 0] = x;
    array[index * 2 + 1] = y;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float[] pt = {event.getX(), event.getY()};
            mInverse.mapPoints(pt);
            int x = (int) pt[0];
            int y = (int) pt[1];
            if (mLastWarpX != x || mLastWarpY != y) {
                mLastWarpX = x;
                mLastWarpY = y;
                warp(pt[0], pt[1]);
                invalidate();
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void warp(float cx, float cy) {
    final float K = 700;
    float[] src = dst; //now you are applying wrap effect on the last effected pixels
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT*2; i += 2) {
        float x = src[i + 0];
        float y = src[i + 1];
        float dx = cx - x;
        float dy = cy - y;
        float dd = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        float d = (float) Math.sqrt(dd);
        float pull = K / (dd + 0.000001f);

        pull /= (d + 0.000001f);
        // android.util.Log.d("skia", "index " + i + " dist=" + d +
        // " pull=" + pull);

        if (pull >= 1) {
            //Log.e("Pull", "Pull >=1");
            dst[i + 0] = cx;
            dst[i + 1] = cy;
        } else {
            //Log.e("Pull", "Pull <1");
            dst[i + 0] = x + dx * pull;
            dst[i + 1] = y + dy * pull;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is I get some sharp edges when distorting the image. What I want is smooth distortion like in the app photo warp.

[What I want (as you can see smooth effect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBhEZ.jpg)

[What I get (as you can see sharp edges)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvR42.jpg)

Any comments, suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?